# Restarting a pull request, with some files that haven't changed since original

Tags: git, github

Over a month ago I put up a pull request on a Github repository, asking for comments.  I got them, and have been taking them into account.

That PR is still up there and by now I've changed enough files in my PR branch that I'm a little leery of simply modifying the existing PR-- the comments are dealing with stale code by now, etc.  Ideally I'd like to close it and open a new one.

My question is how best to do it.  In my local repo the files that were part of the PR, and untouched since, are no longer marked as modified.  If I close the PR how do I push them back up into a new PR with the more recent changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just update the branch your pull request is based off, so in the PR page you'll see both the original commits, the comments made over them, and then the commits you made to address those comments. You have the whole history of that work, and can *audit* it - or something like that.

You could also `rebase` and `push -f` your branch so the old commits get fixed - instead of just adding new ones -, and you'll get a prettier history. You lose the old commits appearing in the PR, so it's harder to see what the comments talk about, but you get a nicer history log.

In anyway, creating a new pull request would lose that relationship between your new changes and the comments you received, which seems to be a shame - nothing better than seeing what issues you were addressing while you made those changes!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, going your way above makes sense.